# Replace a string with another in HTML but no in HTML tags and attributes PHP

Tags: php, html, replace, domdocument

I need to load a HTML (maybe with DOMDocument loadHTML) and then replace all words A with word B but nothing inside an html tag.

This means that in the following html if we need to replace the word 'test' with 'TEST' it will only replace the text 'this is a test' with 'this is a TEST' and will keep intact the id="test"

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
  <div id="test"> this is a test </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What's the question here, exactly?

Comment: If you know how to load html, how to process and then save, you know how to solve your problem. what can we do?

Comment: You want to do it in PHP dynamically when serving the document ?

Comment: You realize, though, that `<html>` is also a tag right? :) okay, thanks for the update

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can't get enough of DOMDocument :)

```
$d = new DOMDocument;
$d->loadHTML($html);

$x = new DOMXPath($d);

foreach ($x->query('//text()') as $node) {
    $node->nodeValue = str_replace('test', 'TEST', $node->nodeValue);
}

echo $d->saveHTML();
```

Not sure if there's any performance loss to always doing a replace on `nodeValue`; otherwise, replace the loop contents with:

```
$s = str_replace('test', 'TEST', $node->nodeValue, $count);
if ($count) {
    $node->nodeValue = $s;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the [Simple html dom parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/):

```
include("simple_html_dom.php");
...
$html = '
<html>
 <head></head>
 <body>
  <div id="test"> this is a test </div>
 </body>
</html>
';

$data = str_get_html($html);
$find = $data->find("div[id='test']",0);
$find->innertext = str_replace("test","TEST",$find->innertext);
$data = $data->save();

echo $data;
```