# PHP preg_match can't replace with number properly

Tags: php, preg-replace

```
$pedit =<<<head
<div class="item"><div var="i_name_10">white gold</div> <div 
var="i_price_10">$5.99</div></div> 
head;

echo preg_replace("/(<[^>]+var=\"i_price_10\"[^>]*>)(.*?)(<\/[^>]+? 
>\s*)/","$1".'100'."$3",$pedit);
```

Result:

```
<div class="item"><div var="i_name_10">white gold</div> 00</div>
```

Expected

```
    <div class="item"><div var="i_name_10">white gold</div><div 
    var="i_name_10">100</div> </div>
```

That seem to happen with any number even when i try casting it as string.

Comment: Related: [Replace html content without replacing the tags or attributes - PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53973366/2943403) and [Replace a string with another in HTML but no in HTML tags and attributes PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10950741/2943403)

Answer (score 1):

Despite the fact that you isolated your backreference as a separate string and concatenate with '100', the parser still reads it as one string. This means the replacement string in your question is equivilent to:

```
'$11' . '00' . '$3'
```

You can isolate the backreference next to a number using braces and skip the concatenation:

```
'${1}100$3'
```

All that said, there are other problems with your regex and [regex is notoriously bad at parsing html](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1767412).  If your goal is to modify the text content of an html string you might consider using DOMDocument:

```
// load your html string into DOMDocument
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($pedit, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
// xpath makes it easier to query for attributes like "var" in this case
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$els = $xpath->query('//div[@var="i_price_10"]');
foreach ($els as $el) {
    // you can do whatever you'd like to the text node here
    $el->textContent = '100';
}
echo $dom->saveHTML();
```